# CSS active li incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a site and I'm a bit out of my league when it comes to the java portion, thus I've used default scripts (as far as I can tell).

When I have my CSS active li class enabled, the menu highlights wrong — the first option is fine, the second option keeps the first [menu] item highlighted, and the final third option highlights the 2nd menu link. After a process of elimination, I'm thinking there's something goofy going on in one of my java scripts, which I cannot pinpoint.

http://test.nineworldsrecords.com

To summarize, the actively viewed section of the page is highlighted incorrectly in the top menu, though I cannot locate the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Java =/= JavaScript. Please show some code.

Comment: Code would be very helpful in finding out what is wrong!

Comment: the problem lies in that either the page does not scroll down quite far enough when clicking the link or the "waypoints" are set too low. this can be shown by just scrolling down the page and watching how the menu items change (i.e. it works when you scroll, not when you click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry mate for the previous solution. I've retested your menu and I saw the real issue.
Here is your answer to your problem:
Replace line 35 from "scripts.js" file from:

```
scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
```

to

```
scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top + ( $('.navigation li.active').data('slide') < dataslide ? 1 : -1 )
```

Good luck!